# C++ how to utilize public int from subclass in a different subclass

Tags: c++

I'm practicing a prototype program for a text-based game with complex character features. I have simplified much of what I already wrote, but I'm new to programming and have run into a problem. 
I want to have a sub-class `WaterBottle` that has an int `drink` of value 3. I want another sub-class `Hydration` to have an int called `hydLvl`. I want a function within the Hydration subclass that is able to add the `drink` value to the `hydLvl` variable when used in the `main` function.

```cpp
class Character {

};

class Hydration : public Character {
    public:
        int hydLvl = 5;
        int hydPrint(void) {
            std::cout << "Hyd Lvl: " << hydLvl << endl;
            return 0;
        }
};

class WaterBottle : public Character {
    public:
        int drink = 3;
};
...
```

So far, I've been unable to successfully utilize the drink variable from the `WaterBottle` class to modify the hydLvl variable from the `Hydration` class.

Comment: What does "utilize the drink variable from the WaterBottle class to modify the hydLvl variable from the Hydration class" mean? That won't happen automatically. You'll need a `setDrink()` type function that does the work for you.

Comment: Shouldn't `WaterBottle` inherit from `Hydration`?

Comment: Tip: Instead of utility "print" methods, have conventional getter/setter methods and handle the display logic in another concern. You're cluttering up your class here with things that aren't unique to Character.

Comment: Does it even make sense for `Hydration` to inherit from `Character`? What is `Hydration` even supposed to represent? If it's a mixin class for "something that can drink liquids" then it would make sense for `Character` to inherit it, rather than it inheriting `Character`.

Comment: The inheritance model here seems wrong. `class X : public Y` does not add features to class `Y`, it creates a whole new class `X` that has everything `Y` does plus whatever else you define. It almost seems like `Character` should have a `hydration` property instead of a subclass.

Comment: The pattern I'd use here is defining `Character` that has `std::vector<item> inventory` with an `Item` base class for "thing that you can put in inventory".

Comment: @tadman Except it would have to be a vector of pointers/references since `item` would probably be polymorphic. ;)

Comment: @cdhowie Probably a smart pointer, but yeah, that!

Comment: Recommendation: [Read a bit about the Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle)

Comment: You can have a function in Hydration that takes a WaterBottle parameter.  That function will have access to the Hydration's hydLvl and the WaterBottle's drink, because it's in Hydration and drink is public in WaterBottle.  Then all it has to do is addition and assignment.  What's the problem?

Comment: Adding to the comments by @tadman, `Hydration` doesn't sound like an inventory item, but it might be in another similar container of the character's properties/statistics.

Comment: If you're thinking that you want to alter a variable in another class, you are likely not thinking abstractly enough. Likely, you want a situation where using the water bottle will increase the hydration level. At this level, do you care how the hydration level is stored? No, you do not. You simply want to tell your `Hydration` object that it just got `x` units of liquid. How much is `x`? You get that by asking the `WaterBottle` object how much hydration it provides. It might seem overly complex to write something like `hydro.add(bottle.amount());`, but it compartmentalizes your logic.